# Laravel CRUD Ajax, can't store data to database

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

hello guys i learn to use jquery ajax on laravel, i found it on internet but i have one problem, in my case i just try to do some simple CRUD, but the program can't store all data to databases although when i try to inspect element, all form data are showing on it , other action like edit,delete,and read data from databases are working correctly but create not working properly, can you help me to figure out my problem. 
ah here my code

here my Jquery and ajax script.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = "/AJAX_INTEGRATED/public/tasks";

    //display modal form for task editing
    $('.open-modal').click(function(){
        var task_id = $(this).val();

        $.get(url + '/' + task_id, function (data) {
            //success data
            console.log(data);
            $('#task_id').val(data.id);
            $('#task').val(data.task);
            $('#description').val(data.description);
            $('#btn-save').val("update");

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        })
    });

    //display modal form for creating new task
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#btn-save').val("add");
        $('#frmTasks').trigger("reset");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

    //delete task and remove it from list
    $('#tasks-list').on('click','.delete-task',function(){
        var task_id = $(this).val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })

        $.ajax({

            type: "DELETE",
            url: url + '/' + task_id,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                $("#task" + task_id).remove();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });

    //create new task / update existing task
    $("#btn-save").click(function (e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = {
            task: $('input[name=task]').val(),
            description: $('input[name=description]').val(),
        }

        //used to determine the http verb to use [add=POST], [update=PUT]
        var state = $('#btn-save').val();

        var type = "POST"; //for creating new resource
        var task_id = $('#task_id').val();;
        var my_url = url;

        if (state == "update"){
            type = "PUT"; //for updating existing resource
            my_url += '/' + task_id;
        }

        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({

            type: type,
            url: my_url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                var task = '<tr id="task' + data.id + '"><td>' + data.id + '</td><td>' + data.task + '</td><td>' + data.description + '</td><td>' + data.created_at + '</td>';
                task += '<td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="' + data.id + '">Edit</button>';
                task += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-task" value="' + data.id + '">Delete</button></td></tr>';

                if (state == "add"){ //if user added a new record
                    $('#tasks-list').append(task);
                }else{ //if user updated an existing record
                    $("#task" + task_id).replaceWith( task );
                }

                $('#frmTasks').trigger("reset");

                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my route.

```html
<?php
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $tasks = Task::all();

    return View::make('welcome')->with('tasks',$tasks);
});

Route::get('/tasks/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::post('/tasks',function(Request $request){
    $task = Task::create($request->all());

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::put('/tasks/{task_id?}',function(Request $request,$task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);

    $task->task = $request->task;
    $task->description = $request->description;

    $task->save();

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::delete('/tasks/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::destroy($task_id);

    return Response::json($task);
});
```

my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Laravel Ajax CRUD Example</title>

    <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-narrow">
        <h2>Laravel Ajax To Do App</h2>
        <button id="btn-add" name="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add New Task</button>
        <div>

            <!-- Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Task</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Date Created</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tasks-list" name="tasks-list">
                    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
                    <tr id="task{{$task->id}}">
                        <td>{{$task->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$task->task}}</td>
                        <td>{{$task->description}}</td>
                        <td>{{$task->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="{{$task->id}}">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-task" value="{{$task->id}}">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- End of Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <!-- Modal (Pop up when detail button clicked) -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Task Editor</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="frmTasks" name="frmTasks" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">

                                <div class="form-group error">
                                    <label for="inputTask" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="task" name="task" placeholder="Task" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="add">Save changes</button>
                            <input type="hidden" id="task_id" name="task_id" value="0">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/ajax-crud.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and when i click "add new task" button on inspect element showing like this 
{task: "Hello", description: "Blasdweas"}
ajax-crud.js:89 {updated_at: "2017-11-05 10:44:02", created_at: "2017-11-05 10:44:02", id: 22}

but only created at and updated at are saved.

Comment: I just had a quick look at the documentation for Laravel (Don't have a whole pile of experience myself). Should you be passing request->all() to the create method. Should it not look something more like it does in the docs. $flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about that, but sure I will try your suggestion. Arghh I stuck for 2 days to fix this problem. And thanks for your answer man. :)

Comment: Cool. Let me know how you get on. If it works I'll post it as an official answer. If it doesn't I'll have a look at it again.